# Проблема с отображением картинки в Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Я делаю flask приложение для конвертации форматов изображений, пользователь должен ввести url изображения и дальше выбрать формат сохранения но это не важно, важно то, что когда он полностью введет url квртинки она дожна отобразиться, но пока url не дейтсвителен, картика будет отображаться некрасивой иконкой, я хочу чтобы тег img был скрыт пока url  не будет загружен без ошибки.
Это тег img src берется из input text url, я пытался сделать так, чтобы при ошибке загрузке срыть img, а впротином случае сделать значение v-show img true, но видемо я сделал что-то не так помогите пожалуйста.
Вот img:

```html
<img :src="url_text" v-on="showImg" v-if="img_is_not_hide" @error="hideImg" id="preview">
```

Вот main.js

```js
const form = new Vue({
    el: "#form",
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
    data: {
        format: "...",
        url_text: "",
        img_is_not_hide: true
    },
    methods: {
        hideImg () {
            this.img_is_not_hide = false
        },
        showImg () {
            this.img_is_not_hide = true
        }
    }
})
```

Помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: Я не силён во Vue, но разве нельзя просто случшать собыите `onload` у изображения и смотреть на его успешность? Хотя наверное - это просто будет обратным тому что вы написали

Answer (score 0):

у меня было что-то похожее, но я не помню как решил тогда

но мне кажется это можно решить через специальный аттрибут `key` который заставит перерисовываться картинку

```html
<img :key="url_text" :src="url_text" v-on="showImg" v-if="img_is_not_hide" @error="hideImg" id="preview">
```

Comment: Ну это и так понятно, вопрос, что это за атрибут или директива.